# To generate random numbers at fixed position

Tags: matlab

Consider i=1 to 10.
I want to generate random nos for odd positions of i only.
Is there any function or method to do so? Please help.

Comment: You mean a vector with random number at odd positions ?

Comment: Question is not clear like this. Please add expected output.

Comment: yes..a vector with random numbers at odd position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have x = zeros(10,1);

It's a bit messy, but the task can be done with:
x(1:2:end) = rand(size(x(1:2:end)))

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this :

```
>> a=[1:10]

a =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> r = randi(100,1,5) % 5 random numbers between  1:100

r =

    49    63    68    40    37

>> a(1:2:10) =r

a =

    49     2    63     4    68     6    40     8    37    10
```